# Type punning pointers via union

Tags: c, unions, type-punning

Can I use type punning with union members which are pointer to signed and unsigned versions of a type? For example, is the following usage of `p.u` guaranteed to work by the standard?

```
void foo(unsigned *u);

int num = 7;
union
{
    int *i;
    unsigned *u;
} p;

p.i = &num;

foo(p.u);
```

Assuming that `num` is non-negative it seems it should be fine on most platforms. I'm wondering whether it's guaranteed that the two pointers will have the same representation in memory?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are very strictly speaking no guarantees that these two pointer types have the same representation in memory. The C standard only guarantees that (6.3.2.3) "A pointer to an object type may be converted to a pointer to a different object type." /--/ "Otherwise, when converted back again, the result shall compare equal to the
original pointer."

To satisfy this requirement in practice, it is however extremely likely that `int*` and `unsigned*` have the same representation in memory. To the point where I wouldn't worry about it.

The type punning itself is otherwise well-defined (6.2.6), as is accessing an object of effective type `int` through an `unsigned int*`, or an object of effective type `unsigned int` through a `int*` (6.5/7 "strict aliasing").

The real question here is why you'd use such a union instead of always accessing the memory by an `unsigned int*` and then cast the de-referenced value to `int` when needed.

Answer (score 0):

The Standard is unclear as to whether an access made via lvalue of a form like:

```
addressOfStructOrUnion->member    or
structOrUnionLvalue.member
```

is for purposes of the aliasing rules considered to performed with an lvalue of the struct or union type, or with an lvalue of the member type.  I don't think there has ever been a consensus among Committee members on this point.

The way clang and gcc interpret the Standard, an lvalue of the form `addressOfStructOrUnion->member` will be presumed incapable of accessing one of the form `addressOfDifferentStructOrUnion->member`, even if the member types are identical.  Further, even though the Standard unambiguously says that an lvalue of the form `addressOfStructOrUnion->memberArray[index]` is equivalent to `*(addressOfStructOrUnion->memberArray+(index))`, which would clearly be an lvalue of the final pointer's target type (which would in turn be the element type of the array), both clang and gcc treat an access made via the expression using bracket notation as though it is made via lvalue of the struct or union type.

It's best to treat the Standard as though it defines two dialects of C, one of which behaves as though N1570 6.5p7 were omitted (which clang and gcc will process when invoked with the `-fno-strict-aliasing` flag), and the other of which is suitable only for programs that will, throughout the lifetime of each individual piece of storage, always access it the same way.

Comment: I start to think that "strict aliasing rule" should newer be introduced. Just rely on inlining and `restrict` to provide compilers enough information to perform aliasing analysis.

Comment: @tstanisl: The rule would have been fine if compilers limited its application to circumstances where a compiler could see that a region of storage was accessed twice within a certain context (which may be drawn narrowly or broadly) using a certain type, and nothing within that context (drawn *the same way*) would suggest the possibility of anything else the storage in conflicting fashion.  In the vast majority of cases where the rule would be useful, there would be nothing that would even remotely suggest the possibility of conflicting accesses, and in the vast majority of cases where it's...

Comment: ...problematic, there will be an identifiable sequence of actions which could convert a reference to an object of the type in question into a pointer to some other type, and then access it.